# how to show pagination details in primeng datatable

Tags: angular, primeng

In primeng datatable i am using filter and getting pagination.
But want to pagination details.

eg:

showing 1 to 10 of 100 entries,

I am using datatable from following link.

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-5.2.7/#/datatable/filter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First set an event handler for onPage event which is triggered whenever pagination happens. Then set the custom pagination string on that handler.

```
    <p-dataTable [value]="cars" [rows]="10" [paginator]="true" [pageLinks]="3" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[5,10,20]" (onPage)="setMyPagination(event)">
        <p-header>List of Cars</p-header>
        <p-column field="vin" header="Vin"></p-column>
        <p-column field="year" header="Year"></p-column>
        <p-column field="brand" header="Brand"></p-column>
        <p-column field="color" header="Color"></p-column>
        <ng-template pTemplate="paginatorLeft">
            {{myPaginationString}}
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="paginatorRight">
           {{myPaginationString}}
        </ng-template>
    </p-dataTable>`  
    myPaginationString = "";

setMyPagination(event) {
    //event.first: Index of first record being displayed 
    //event.rows: Number of rows to display in new page 
    //event.page: Index of the new page 
    //event.pageCount: Total number of pages
    let startRow = event.first + 1;
    let endRow =  startRow + event.rows;
    let totalRows = this.cars.length;
    this.myPaginationString  = "showing "+startRow +" to "+ endRow +" of "+ totalRows  +" entries"
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Tuhin Das, can u please provide  a working demo on stackblitz

Comment: sure let me get back to you with the demo

Comment: yes but will require to fetch total records from the filtered list currently it is taking the whole data length as total records

Answer (score 3):

You could do this:

```
<ng-template pTemplate="paginatorleft" let-state>
        Showing {{(state.page  * state.rows) + 1}} to {{state.rows * (state.page + 1)}} of {{state.totalRecords}} entries
  </ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

For adding Pagination to PrimeNG Table as follows -

[image]

1. Create a backing object to hold the total number of records to be rendered using PrimeNG Datatable

   ```
    this.totalRecords=this.books.length;
   ```

Next we adding the following attributes for the datatable-

- paginator - We set the paginate property to true to enable Pagination
  for the datatable
- rows - We define how many rows should be displayed per page.
- rowsPerPageOptions - Allow the user to choose the number of rows user
  wants per page.
- totalRecords - The total number of records the data table will hold.
  We define this backing object above.
- pageLinks - Show the number of Pagination links.

  ```
   <p-table [columns]="cols" [value]="books" [paginator]="true" [rows]="10" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[5,10,15,20]"
            totalRecords="totalRecords" pageLinks="3">
            <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
              <tr>
                <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
                  {{col.header}}
                </th>
              </tr>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
              <tr>
                <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
                  {{rowData[col.field]}}
                </td>
              </tr>
            </ng-template>
          </p-table>
  ```

**Reference - [PrimeNG Tutorial - DataTable Pagination (Paginator) Example with Source Code and Video Tutorial](https://www.codeusingjava.com/angular/primeng/prime7)**